# Integral similar to Beta function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function, beta-function

I am trying to calculate the integral
$$\int_{1}^{2} y^{k-1}(y-1)^{-1/2}dy,$$
where $k$ is positive integers. But the integral domain is a little different from the definition of the Beta function. I have tried to replace $y$ by $y+1$, so we get following integral
$$\int_{0}^{1} (y+1)^{k-1}y^{-1/2}dy.$$
It seems no help. I hope the integral above can be expressed in terms of the Beta function. Is it possible? Or there is a simplified result?

Comment: How do you feel about the [incomplete Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) and an expression involving $\Gamma$s?

Comment: It's ok. Do you have some ideas? I am not familiar with the incomplete Beta function.@EricTowers

Comment: Well, a computer algebra system reports that your definite integral is $$-B_{1/2}\left( \frac{1}{2} - k,\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{\pi} \, \Gamma \left( \frac{1}{2} - k \right)}{\Gamma(1-k)}  \text{.}  $$

Comment: Is $B_{1/2}(1/2-k,1/2)$ well defined when $k$ is a positive integer?@EricTowers

Comment: Yes.  It's between $0$ and $B(1/2-k,1/2)$.

Comment: When I replace $y$ by$x/(1-x)$, I have get the expression of the incomplete Beta function, but without gamma. @EricTowers

Comment: What if we set $y=1-u$?

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with the gaussian hypergeometric function, the definite integral is
$$2\, \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},1-k;\frac{3}{2};-1\right)$$ This is identical to the result given by @Eric Towers.

Both formulae are valid for any value of $k$ (positive, negative, rational or not and complex)